# picking dropdown option with selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I went through a number very useful resources on Selenium parsing here, e.g. https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/12029/how-do-i-work-with-dropdowns-in-selenium-webdriver but could make my code work, so thought I would ask..

I'd like to pick up a dropdown option for example from ebay.com:

if I go to www.ebay.com and type "Minolta Rokkor", there will be a drop down menu, from which I want to pick, say, "minolta rokkor 40mm f/2".

I'm able to type in the query, but even getting the list of options isn't working for me. Would appreciate any help. Here's my code:

```
browser.get("https://www.ebay.com")
time.sleep(6)
e = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("gh-tb")
e[0].send_keys("Minolta Rokkor")
time.sleep(5)
dropdown_web_element = browser.find_element_by_id("gh-ac")
select_box = Select(dropdown_web_element)
time.sleep(1)
for o in select_box.options:
    print o.text
```

Comment: It didn't give me a dropdown option when I type any words.

Comment: hmm, it definitely gives them to me - even with selenium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the "dropdown" is not actually a "select field". It may look like one. It may sort of function like one, but it isn't one.

[image]

The options are part of a `ul` that are styled to *look* like a select field.

You can use the following to obtain all options in the dropdown

```
browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//ul[contains(@class, 'ui-autocomplete')]//li/a")
```

To click an option is a bit more tricky because the text isn't just inside the `a` tag, some of the text is surrounded by `b` tags, so doing so with xpath can be annoying. Here's what I came up with

```py
browser.get("https://www.ebay.com")
time.sleep(6)
e = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("gh-tb")
e[0].send_keys("Minolta Rokkor")
time.sleep(5)
dropdown_web_element = browser.find_element_by_id("gh-ac")
select_options = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//ul[contains(@class, 'ui-autocomplete')]//li/a")
time.sleep(1)
for ele in select_options:
    if ele.text == 'minolta rokkor 40mm f/2':
        click_id = ele.get_attribute('id')

browser.find_element_by_id(click_id).click()
```

Comment: Thanks, that was really helpful!